# Adding PDF to Outook

Tags: vba, pdf, outlook

Can you please help me with that code, I am a beginner trying to work it out.
I am creating a PDF file from specific sheet (first page) and I'd like to add it to an email with CC address.

```
Sub zapisz()

Dim ThisFile As String
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

ThisFile = Range("b8").Value & " " & Range("b9").Value & " " & Range("g8").Value & " " & Range("h8").Value

ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:= _
    ThisFile, Quality:= _
    xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=False, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    From:=1, To:=1, OpenAfterPublish:=False


Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
With OutMail
    .To = ""
    .CC = "monika@xx.pl"
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Oferta xxx"
    .Body = "Szanowni Państwo, w załączniku przesyłam ofertę."
    .Attachments.Add (ThisFile & "*" & ".pdf")
    .Display
End With
On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
 End With

 End Sub`
```

Comment: And what is the problem? Are you getting a particular error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good job for using late binding, this is really a good practice, when asking questions in StackOverflow! In general, give it a try like this:

```
Sub zapisz()

        Dim ThisFile As String
        Dim OutApp As Object
        Dim OutMail As Object

        ThisFile = Range("b8") 'include the rest of your range here for the name

        ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
            ThisFile, Quality:= _
            xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=False, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
            From:=1, To:=1, OpenAfterPublish:=False        

        Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        With OutMail
            .To = ""
            .CC = "monika@xx.pl"
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = "Oferta xxx"
            .Body = "Szanowni Panstwo, w zalaczniku przesylam oferte."
            .Attachments.Add (ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisFile & ".pdf")
            .Display
        End With
        'more of your code here
End Sub
```

Make sure that the initial Excel file is saved somewhere (anywhere in your PC would work). Once it is saved, you would be able to use `ThisWorkbook.Path`, in order to add the attachment.
I have chagned `ThisFile = Range("B8")`, but you can fix it back once you want.

You may consider removing `On Error GoTo 0`, it is only needed if you are using some error catcher like `On Error Resume Next` or `On Error GoTo zapisz_Error` before it.